# R Shiny sequential use of modals

Tags: r, shiny

I want to check some user inputted data, testing some conditions and alerting via `modalDialog()` to get more user input (e.g. prompt `X is NA; is this correct? Y/N`).

However, I have found that if I put multiple `showModal(modalDialogFunction())` calls in an `observeEvent`, only the last one will be  evaluated for the user in that the modal pops up, etc. The `print` statements verify the conditions are met.

How can I execute sequential modals in this or a similar format?

Single file app: play around with `numericInput()`s to see how modals are executed.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("first", label="First", value=0),
      numericInput("second", label="Second", value=0)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("click", label="Click")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  firstModal <- function(){
    modalDialog(
      p("First is greater than zero"),
      actionButton("clickHere", label="Click to continue")
    )
  }

  secondModal <- function(){
    modalDialog(
      p("Second is greater than zero"),
      actionButton("clickAgain", label="Click to continue again")
    )
  }

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    if(input$first>0){
      print("First is greater than 0")
      showModal(firstModal())
    }

    if(input$second>0){
      print("Second is greater than 0")
      showModal(secondModal())
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: have you tried using two different `observeEvent`s?

Comment: I would prefer not to, as that will be much harder to keep track of when adding many such conditions (i.e. basing the next test on the buttons in the previous modal, which will require building successive conditions into new `observeEvents` on new buttons created in new modals, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I found that it is not possible to have two input buttons having the same ID and being visible at the same time. To solve that problem, the button that opens your very first modal needs a different ID - all the "Next"-Buttons in the Modals can share one ID, since they are never visible at the same time. Check this working example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      actionButton("openFirst", label="Click")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # function to create a modal, can be different functions as well
  makeModal <- function(text){
    modalDialog(
      footer=list(actionButton("click", label="Click to continue"), modalButton("Close")),
      numericInput("number", "Enter a number", value=0),
      p(text)
    )
  }

  # open the first modal
  observeEvent(input$openFirst, {
    showModal(makeModal("first one opened"))
  })

  # open a new modal at button click.
  observeEvent(input$click, {
    if(input$number > 15){ showModal(makeModal("input was greater than 15!"))
    }else if(input$number > 5){ showModal(makeModal("input was greater than five!"))
    }else{
      showModal(makeModal("Input was not greater than five!"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Nice, I like this solution

Comment: Can you expand your answer to address showing modals based on conditions checked against external data (i.e. not dependent on `modalCounter`)? I want to show/not show a modal (and collect input from that modal) based on whether some external condition is met, like the `numericInput`s in my question. I don't see how I can adapt your answer to that.

Comment: For this behaviour, no counter is needed. Adjusted the example to react on input in modal.

Comment: @shosaco this is not quite the issue I am facing. In my example, the unexpected behavior happens when *both* the conditions in `observeEvent(input$click, {...` are met. In that case, only the last modal is executed. This happens when there are no overlapping ids as well.

Comment: and this is correct in my opinion, because both conditions are met and you are not using `if(){ }else{ }`...

Comment: Can you explain why, in my example, when both conditions are met, `firstModal()` is not run (which is inside the first condition; the `print` function there gets executed)?

Comment: The first modal is shown, but before you can see it, the second one is opened. Insert  a `return()` after `showModal(firstModal())` to prevent this... or simply use `else`

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought might be happening. However, my question is concerned with showing them sequentially. I don't want to use `else`, because it is not `this` or `that`, I want modal input based on the first condition or not, and on the second condition or not (up to however many conditions I have). If you replace the modal calls with `shinyjs::alert()` you will get the behavior I expected, where the alerts "stack". This is probably a JS vs R distinction, but it is the behavior I am ultimately after (though perhaps it is not possible how I tried).

Comment: I got you now. Unfortunately, not sure how one would do that with modals. Check if `validate(need(condition1, message1), need(condition2, message2))` would be an alternative...